# Is there a way to make an external request on my site use the same IP as the person that connected instead my website host?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, heroku

I am currently hosting a test express website on Heroku , and from my site I make requests to external api's , all fine and good but the problem is the external requests are sent from my heroku nodes ip address , not from the ip of the user that connected , is there a way to make the actual user make the request instead of the node/pc hosting my website ?

all the requests use standard http

Comment: you can do them in the frontend instead of the backend and it will do the job, apart from express, what other technology are you using?

Comment: and how can I make the request in the front end ? you mean like making a js script to the website page that sends the requests ? and I am using just express , heroku , node js and ejs